# Is it possible with generics?

Tags: java, generics

I have class:

```
public class GenericDAO<T, ID extends Serializable> {
private final EntityManager em;
private final Class<T> entityClass;
public GenericDAO(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
    ParameterizedType genericSuperClass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    this.entityClass = (Class<T>) genericSuperClass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
}
```

If I extend this class all works fine. Now I want to use this class directly (see code belove, CRUDBean is implementation of CRUDService) - it is necessary to rewrite constructor to get particular class.

```
@Remote(CRUDService.class)
@Stateless
public class CRUDBean<T extends EntityBase> implements CRUDService<T> {
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public long size(String whereClause, Map<String, Object> whereParameters) {
    return new GenericDAO<T, Long>(entityManager).size(whereClause, whereParameters);
}
}
```

How to write such generics service?

Comment: Is this is Java? Please add the appropriate tag either way, generics exists in many languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would need to create a separate constructor.

Your current constructor assumes that `this` is an instance of a subclass of `GenericDAO`, and it uses that fact to get the type parameter for you through `getClass().getGenericSuperclass().getActualTypeArguments()`.

To use `GenericDAO` directly, you should create a `GenericDAO` constructor which takes the entity class (whatever type `T` really is) as an argument. Then provide the entity class in `CRUDBean.size()` or wherever you need to instantiate your `GenericDAO`.

If you don't have the actual class available in `CRUDBean`, have three choices:

1. Create a `CRUDBean` constructor which takes the entity class as an argument.
2. Add a parameter to `size()` which takes the entity class as an argument.
3. Use the same trick as in the current `GenericDAO` constructor to get it, but with `getGenericInterfaces()` instead.

Comment: How can I create it? Problem is that CrudService (and it's implementation CrudBean) is EJB service (@EJB private CRUDService crudSvc;) I don't know how to pass the argument :(

Comment: Extended answer to take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an explicit "type token", rather than reusing a class.

Comment: I have some 50 entities. I don't want to create 50 interfaces (CRUDEntity1Service), 50 typed implementations (CRUDEntity1Bean), 50 typed DAOs (Entity1DAO) ...

Answer (score 0):

The usual, and easiest, way around this to pass an instance of the class to the constructor:

```
public GenericDAO(EntityManager em, Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.em = em;
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
public long size(String whereClause, Map<String, Object> whereParameters, Class<T> entityClass) {
    return new GenericDAO<T, Long>(entityManager, entityClass).size(whereClause, whereParameters);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. In real, the CrudService has some 20 methods (so I can add entityClass to each of them). Is there another way how to do it once?

Comment: You could create a wrapper that you pass the entityClass to in the constructor then have it delegate to an inner GenericDAO object's methods adding in the entityClass to all calls - you would have to write the delegation 20 times, but the client classes would only have to pass the entityClass once